# How should we use differential "dx" in deriving Tabular formula

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am learning repeated integration with the  Tabular method. I see textbooks or web sites prove the method, but  most of the times, they  either do not explain each step or just skip with (...). I try to prove it myself  by going through  each step.  I am not sure if my manipulations of differential "$dx$" are legitimate, and in general how to justify them.

I started with  with  (uv)'=u'v+vu'

$\frac {d(uv)} {dx} 
= \frac {du} {dx}v+ u\frac {dv} {dx}$  $\to$ (Q1: Can I  simply multiply both sides  by $dx$?)

$d(uv)= vdu+udv$

$\int uv =\int udv+\int vdu$

$\int udv=\int uv -\int vdu$  $    $  (I)

Set $\frac {du} {dx}=u^1$ ,  $\frac {dv^{-1}}{dx}=v$ $\to$  $du= u^1dx$,   $v=\frac {dv^{(-1)}} {dx}$

$\int vdu= \int u^1dx$$\frac {dv^{(-1)}} {dx}$  $\to$ $\int u^1dv^{-1}$  (Q2:  Can I directly cancel $dx$ from  both numerator and denominator?)

$\int udv= uv -\int u^1dv^{-1}  $

Repeating similar steps $\to$

**$\int udv=$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^iu^i v^{-i} +\int (-1)^nu^n dv^{-n}$**   $    $

**$\int udv=$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^iu^i v^{-i} +\int (-1)^{n+1}u^{n+1} dv^{-(n+1)}$**   $    $  (II)

which is equivalent to common expression
**$\int udv=$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^iu^i v^{-i} +\int (-1)^{n+1}u^{n+1} v^{-(n)}dx$**   $    $  (II')

Comment: Thanks!  I missed this  and corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating dx as a fraction is technically wrong but I don't think you'll make any 'big mistakes' due to it. As in, even though it is an incorrect operation, it is one which produces correct results.

Anyways for repetead integration by parts, there is a faster derivation by a switch of notation, let $f_{i} $ denote the ith derivative of $f$, so for example $f_1$ is first derivative of $f$.

Now, we can write: $$(fg)_{-1}= f_{-1} g - (f_{-1} g_1)_{-1}= f_{-1}g -f_{-2} g_{1} + (f_{-2} g_{2})_{-1} $$

Repeating the above method n times,

$$ (fg)_{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n f_{-i} g_{i-1}(-1)^{i+1}+ (-1)^n (f_{-n}g_{n})_i$$

[refer here](https://archive.org/details/integralcalculus00edwarich/page/50/mode/2up) page-50 of the Joseph Edward book

Comment: thanks!  I read your paper and still do not understand your first line here.  How do you extend combination formula to negative  and apply here?

Comment: whut, wdym by combination formula to negative @BrightStar?

Comment: I thought you use this formula : https://miro.medium.com/max/443/1*uVFGIVq5F_r5nWtD4-lXyg.png.

Comment: I actually got this technique from an odl calculus book I read [refer page-50](https://archive.org/details/integralcalculus00edwarich/page/50/mode/2up) of the book

Comment: Got it! BTW, really like your paper, very cool:-)